# Unreliable NFS with large number files in a directory

Tags: nfs

I have a NFS directory mounted on a host. That directory has 0.6 million log files now, and will have 1.6 million eventually. The files are small, most of them are less than 1MB.

The problem is that I could not reliably find all files of a day in that directory.

If I run such a command below, I should get 4320 files for a day, but I could get any number from 1 to 4320, for example:

```
$ find /mnt/log -type f -name "some-prefix-rolling.log.2015-07-05*" | wc -l
2548
```

I have to read this directory as it is. I could not make any change, e.g. put one day's log files in one folder, because some other applications depend on this setting.

The mount options are: ro,noatime,bg,hard,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,vers=3

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Very few filesystems can handle such a large number of files in a single directory without severe performance problems. Split them into multiple directories.

Comment: I would agree with @MichaelHampton, trying to find a way to make the application that relies on files in that directory to search a hierarchy would be a good option.  Alternately would it be possible to zip/compress a days files using `gzip` or something similar, then add an extra step before the application runs that unpacks the appropriate day(s) logs from the .gz?  It seems like a hassle, but if creating subdirectories is not an option packing and unpacking the files into a zipped format might be the best option.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: while it would be ideal to use subdirs, modern filesystem as XFS and ZFS should have no problem in managing millions of file per directory. Non up-to-date userspace tools can have problem, though.

Answer (score 2):

While storing files in subdirs would be ideal, the right (and expected) behavior is not what you are seeing. Some hints to track down the problem:

- **check your source filesystem:** if you run your command directly on the data source, does it complete correctly?
- for so many files, your source filesystem should be **XFS or ZFS**. Avoid EXT4 and BTRFS
- **try to toggle client-side caching** ([FS-cache module)](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-fscache.html)
- does a simple **`ls -al | wc -l`** return consistent results?

Answer (score 1):

[This post gives some of the upper limits for filesystems.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466521/how-many-files-can-i-put-in-a-directory) Regardless of the "hard limit" of how many files can be stored in a directory, you will very quickly run into performance issues...In the 10's of thousands of files, not the 100's of thousands, especially if you are using a utility like *find* which has to parse the entire directory.